# Xamarin Forms: How to change the color the "back" symbol in the toolbar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to change the color of the back symbol on the toolbar, which is currently black of the toolbar. For visual clarity, here a screenshot with the "back" arrow top left. I already changed the color of the text and the background, as you see in the screenshot.

[Screenshot: Contentpage with black "back" arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ANwg.png)

The project is splitted in `Client`, `Client.Android` and `Client.iOS`. 
The App is currently mainly targeted for Android, but we want to keep the door open for iOS.

If there is anything missing i will try to paste it here too.

MasterDetailsPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
   public partial class MasterDetailPage1: MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MasterDetailPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += this.ListView_ItemSelected;
        }

        protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
        {
            if(child is NavigationPage page)
            {                 
                page.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("343A40");
                page.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("343A40");
                page.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("FFFFFF");
            }

            base.OnChildAdded(child);
        }
}
```

ReportConfigurationPage.xaml.cs

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Company.Client.Views.ReportConfigurationPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollView" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout x:Name="BaseStackLayout" Orientation="Vertical">     
            <!-- Input controls -->
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**UPDATE:**
Ah thanks, it was the `DrawerArrowStyle` in that needed to be defined and assigned in the styles.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#219198</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#219198</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#219198</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90531/navigationpage-bartextcolor-should-also-change-color-of-back-arrow-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concept in Android called the [Material design](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/).

Since Xamarin has adopted the Native Java Android Behavior in Xamarin.Android what happens is that the Android application picks the theme in its styles.xml file and uses that style to set the bar background colour.

But of course, there is a workaround. Whatever changes that you need to do on the Android side you will have to update it in the style file for it for eg:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
   </style>

 <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
 <item name="spinBars">true</item>
 <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="colorPrimary">#003399</item>
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#003399</item>
 <item name="colorControlHighlight">#003399</item>
 <item name="colorAccent">#012348</item>
 <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
 </style>

 </resources>
```

A change in colour here will directly reflect there, for eg ColorPrimary is your toolbar background colour (BarBackgroundColor).

**UPDATE**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
 app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then get the toolbar something like this:

```
var toolbar=yourActivityContext.Window.DecorView.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Your_Color);
//In case of hex color 
toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ebebeb"));
```

Comment: Ah, thanks that helped. Is the stuff around DrawerArrowStyle documented somewhere?  I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Sure no problem. In regards to the DrawerArrowStyle is a part of the [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle) you will find all the information that you need there